# How to include ? and / in XML tag

Tags: xml, w3c

I need to have an XML with below tag

```
<Customer_In_Rental?>No</Customer_In_Rental?>
```

The `?` is not accepted, hence I tried it like

```
<Customer_In_Rental&#63;>No</Customer_In_Rental&#63;>
```

the XML is not well-formed even after this.

How to use `?` in my XML tag.  Similarly, I need to use `/` also

```
<Four/Six>No</Four/Six>
```

any quick help is appreciated.

Comment: Neither question mark nor solidus (/) is allowed in element names, so what you want is not XML.

Answer (score 0):

Neither `?` nor `/` are allowed in XML tags per the [W3C XML BNF for component names](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-NameStartChar):

> ```
> NameStartChar ::= ":" | [A-Z] | "_" | [a-z] | [#xC0-#xD6] | [#xD8-#xF6] |
>                   [#xF8-#x2FF] | [#x370-#x37D] | [#x37F-#x1FFF] |
>                   [#x200C-#x200D] | [#x2070-#x218F] | [#x2C00-#x2FEF] |
>                   [#x3001-#xD7FF] | [#xF900-#xFDCF] | [#xFDF0-#xFFFD] |
>                   [#x10000-#xEFFFF]
> NameChar      ::= NameStartChar | "-" | "." | [0-9] | #xB7 | [#x0300-#x036F] |
>                   [#x203F-#x2040]
> Name          ::= NameStartChar (NameChar)*
> ```

You'll have to find alternatives means of expressing your intent.

For `?`, consider a `Boolean` or `Predicate` suffix, or simply omit and allow the name itself or a schema to communicate the boolean intent.

For `/`, consider `-` or `_`.

Comment: Thanks, I took the alternate means of having an attribute to have the special characters...

Comment: @JBJ:  How do you mean that you used attributes rather than elements to have special characters?   Neither XML element nor XML attributes can include `?` or `/` characters in their *names*; both can include those characters in their *values*.

Comment: ```
<element name="Customer In Rental?">No</element>                                              ```

Comment: @JBJ: Cool, but hopefully you didn't literally use a tag of `element` for your element.