# Allowed symbols in XML element name

Tags: xml

The symbols: hyphen `-`, under-score `_` and period `.` are allowed in element name.
The XML example is valid.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<student>
   <first-name>George</first-name>
   <phone.mobile>(011) 123-4567</phone.mobile>
   <native_language>English</native_language>
   <city />
</student>
```

Is there any other symbol that is also allowed in XML element name?

Comment: Surely you could Google/Bing this question? Please see: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1422451)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right: Letter, digit, hyphen, underscore and period.

One may use any Unicode letter.

And of course one may prefix the names with *name space* + colon.

Answer (score 11):

The characters allowed in XML element names are given by the [W3C XML BNF for component names](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-NameStartChar):

> ```
> NameStartChar ::= ":" | [A-Z] | "_" | [a-z] | [#xC0-#xD6] | [#xD8-#xF6] |
>                   [#xF8-#x2FF] | [#x370-#x37D] | [#x37F-#x1FFF] |
>                   [#x200C-#x200D] | [#x2070-#x218F] | [#x2C00-#x2FEF] |
>                   [#x3001-#xD7FF] | [#xF900-#xFDCF] | [#xFDF0-#xFFFD] |
>                   [#x10000-#xEFFFF]
> NameChar      ::= NameStartChar | "-" | "." | [0-9] | #xB7 | [#x0300-#x036F] |
>                   [#x203F-#x2040]
> Name          ::= NameStartChar (NameChar)*
> ```

### See also

- [Is a colon a legal first character in an XML tag name?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40445735/290085)
- [Represent space and tab in XML tag](https://stackoverflow.com/q/514635/290085)
- [How to include ? and / in XML tag](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59621748/290085)
- [Encoding space character in XML name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46634193/290085)

---

Comment: Good to know the formal definition. It's surprising to see the many Unicode code-point ranges as acceptable start characters. In practice, at least in .NET, only _some_ of them work, namely accented Latin letters (e.g, `Á`) and _some_ Greek letters (e.g, `Π` works, whereas `Ͱ` does not). Do you know why?

Comment: @mklement0: Sorry, I wasn't involved in the standardization process behind the characters allowed in XML component names and do not know the rationale, nor do I know why .NET might not support the full range.